# Getting "invalid platform app" while trying to retrieve authorization code on Instagram

Tags: oauth, postman, facebook-access-token, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get an authorization code to exchange for a user access token to gain access to the Instagram Basic Graph API. I've followed the directions on the [Facebook Developer Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) and am stuck on authenticating the user. I've tried loading the authorization uri:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

on the browser, which returned:

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app"}

I've also tried using Postman to perform a GET request as [described by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize/), and the response returns 404, shown below:

[screenshot of postman GET request attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RFRJ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, and it is impossible to find a solution

Comment: This works with POST instead. But then, I am unable to load the oauth page on the browser. Because html form sends urlencoded form data